# Error 404. Using IIS7.5 URL Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: iis, redirect, ssl, https, http-status-code-404

### Problem

I am getting an annoying 404 error.

- I type in http://myapplication.herp.derp.edu (the url is made up for purposes of illustrating my problem) and see 404.
- I then type in https://myapplication.herp.derp.edu and everything works just fine.

In short, https redirect is not working. I have IIS7.5 application and using URL Rewrite Module 2.0 by Microsoft.

### Code

I have followed the directions [here](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7USHit5mhY) on doing IIS HTTP to HTTPS redirect.

### Attempts

- I have redone the IIS process. Nothing. Same issue.
- Tried off instead of ^OFF$
- Googling. Came up empty. Thus hope this question can help future users.

Clearly, I am not understanding my problem. I know 404 means client can contact server, but someone the server is not facilitating my request properly. What confuses me is that I thought the procedures given above would make this a very simple procedure.

All I am trying to do is get it to where not matter if I put in myapplication.herp.derp.edu or http address, it can redirect.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR:

Make sure you have

- an *HTTP* binding on port `80`

  - Select your website
  - Click `Bindings`
  - Click `Add...` and add an HTTP binding for your hostname on port `80`
- Disabled `Require SSL`

  - Select your website
  - Open `SSL Settings`
  - Un-check `Require SSL`

## Explanation:

`Http 404` indicates that the resource requested was not found. In other words, the web server is telling you that *no resource exists* at the URL `http://myhostname.com:80/` (port written explicitly for clarity).

Since you are configuring your IIS website to use HTTPS,

you likely *removed* the HTTP binding

```
http/All Unassigned:80:myhostname.com
```

and *added* the HTTPS binding

`https/All Unassigned:443:myhostname.com`

As a result, any requests to `http://myhostname.com:80/` route to *nowhere*.

If you have a binding on port `80`, you should not receive an `Http 404`.

Also, as mentioned in the tl;dr, make sure you don't have `Require SSL` enabled, otherwise you will reveive `Http 403` (resource forbidden).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I could not get URL rewrite 2.0 to work. The solution was to create an empty second website on IIS with a webconfig. I then told it to http reroute from http://myapplication.herp.derp.edu to https://myapplication.herp.derp.edu.